# How would I go about making a local highscore table for my game?(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

Well, I made a quick whack-a-mole game in javascript. I have a counter that counts the number of clicks on the mole. My animate function is as so

```
    function animate0(pos) {
    pos %= urls.length;
    var animation0 = document.getElementById('animation0');
    var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    animation0.src = urls[pos];
    if (pos == 1) { // only make onclick when have a certain image
        animation0.onclick = function() {
            counter.innerHTML = parseInt(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        animation0.onclick = function() {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        animate0(++pos);
    }, (Math.random()*500) + 1000);
}
```

I display the counter via this code,

```
<div id='counter'>0</div>
```

Although this is un-related, this is how I display the animation,

```
<img id='animation0' src ='http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif'/>
```

I can't figure out how to make a local computer highscore table(perhaps with 5 or so spots for scores). Help?
Thanks,
Steven

Answer (score 0):

Use [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp) or [HTML5 databases](http://www.webkit.org/demos/sticky-notes/index.html).

A really bad cookie example:
    `setCookie('highscores', '100,120,130,140,150')`

And later

```
var highscores = getCookie('highscores').split(',') //now contains [100,120...]
```

Alternatively, you could store a json object as a string if you wanted to store names and other data. The data format might look like this:

```
[{name: 'STK', score: 1100}, {name: 'ASS', score:'1000'}]
```

You would need to use a JSON handling library (in jquery, or something else) to stringify your array and then parse it later.

Comment: I figured, do you have an example?